# Watch can not receive reply from phone with WatchConnectivity

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

Test with iphone11(14.6) and watch series3(7.5)

In my project, I use WatchConnectivity between phone and watch to communication,
When watch send message with below code, every time run is OK.

```
wcSession.sendMessage(message as [String : Any], replyHandler: nil)
```

But when watch send message need reply, it seems error.

```
wcSession.sendMessage(message) { (reply) in
    
} errorHandler: { (error) in
        
}
```

In Phone with below code to deal with request

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
    
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {

}
```

I debug the code,  didReceiveMessage with reply data can be called, but watch can not receive the reply. So what’s my problem, Before the mobile and watch update, everything is good, every update will cause problems, how to ensure the stability of the app?Thank you very much.

Comment: What errors are being reported? Ideally you should supply a minimum app example so that others can attempt to recreate what you're experiencing. For example, you've left out your wcsession initialization code. That's an obvious area where things might be going wrong. But i don't know because you haven't supplied it.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply @Eric Shieh, Re-pair the phone and watch, problem was solved.